# LINQ - Select Max of two values if count > 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have some `LINQ`that brings back some data. It consists of two properties the ChannelType and the ChannelName. Sometimes the channel type will be null and its count only 1, because the channel hasn't been set yet.

The LINQ query:

```
var channels = (from channel in db.UriData
                join device in db.Devices on channel.SerialNumber equals device.SerialNumber
                join active in db.ActiveChannels on channel.ChannelName equals active.ChannelName
                where channel.ChannelName.Contains(active.ChannelName) && 
                device.Active &&
                channel.SerialNumber == serial
                select new { channel.ChannelName, channel.ChannelType }).Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ChannelName);
```

The data returned from the `LINQ` query:

```
{ ChannelName = "v1", ChannelType = null }
{ ChannelName = "v1", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v2", ChannelType = null }
{ ChannelName = "v2", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v3", ChannelType = null }
{ ChannelName = "v3", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v4", ChannelType = null }
```

From the data, you will see there are two values for the ChannelName, one is null and one is not. I want to be able to select the `Max()` value, so I can ignore the null where there are two channel names. The `Max()` will deal with the single ChannelName that is null as shown in the first entry in the data.

How do I select the `Max()` and remove the nulls where there is more than one ChannelName. For example, if we use ChannelName v1 as shown in the data, we can see that there are two v1's. I want to get the Max() and ignore/remove the null value where there is more than one v1.

I am assuming that I can to do this with another `LINQ` query, such as:

```
var c = channels.Select(x => new { x.ChannelName, x.ChannelType }).Max();
```

Expected outcome:

```
{ ChannelName = "v1", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v2", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v3", ChannelType = "Electricity" }
{ ChannelName = "v4", ChannelType = null }
```

TIA

Comment: there are 3 v1 actually

Comment: How exactly do you want to call `.Max()` on strings?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd show what you expect the results to be - particularly for `v3` and `v1` where there are *three* types: null, Electricity and kWh.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I have added the revised data, query and outcome

Comment: To simply skip results where channel type is null, the `where` predicate should take only "where `channel.ChannelType !=null`".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen this will then ignore the null where I need to keep it. I have updated the data and outcome if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `GroupBy`. Basically you group all channels by name (Key) and then sort all values to get the first one matching your criteria:

```
var result = channels
    .GroupBy(i => i.ChannelName)
    .Select(i => new 
    { 
        ChannelName = i.Key, 
        ChannelType = i.OrderByDescending(v => v.ChannelType)
                       .First()
                       .ChannelType
    });
```

Comment: That misses the null value at v4. If the ChannelName count is 2 then I get rid of the null. If the count is 1, then I have to keep the null.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin it works fine on my end (for the data set you supplied in your question). It doesn't remove nulls it always takes `First()` element. I might have misunderstood your question. I'll check again.

Comment: If I wanted to add another field in the select how do I do that? I want to add a `bool` called calculated, I have tried but it doesn't recognize it. I have changed the first query to bring the calculated field back, but it sees it as a anonymous type

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin I assume that you want to get the `calculated` field of your channel. You retrieve it the same way you retireved `ChannelType` which is `.Select(i => new { /*...*/ Calculated = i.OrderBy(v => v.ChannelType).First().calculated  })`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            var results = channels.Where(x => x.ChannelType != null)
                .Select(x => new { index = int.Parse(x.ChannelName.Replace("v", "")), channel = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.channel.ChannelType)
                .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.index))
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().channel)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _channels = new List<(string, string)>();

foreach(var c in channels)
{
    var channeltypes = channels.Where(x => x.ChannelName == c.ChannelName && x.ChannelType != null);
    if(channeltypes.Any())
    {
        _channels.Add((channeltypes[0].ChannelName, channeltypes[0].ChannelType));
    } else {
        _channels.Add((c.ChannelName, null));
    }
}
```